# How to change file association for files opened in Dolphin from command line in GNOME?

Tags: command-line, default-programs, mime-type, dolphin, xdg-open

I would like to change several default applications for files opened in Dolphin. I know I could do it manually with `kcmshell4 filetypes`, `keditfiletype` or however else but is there a way how to change file associations for Dolphin in terminal? Would be nice if I didn't have to do it manually for every single file type every time I change distribution.

`kde-open` successfully ignores everything set with `xdg-mime` and all following files:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

I guess one way how to solve this would be to detach Dolphin from using `kde-open` and use `gnome-open` or `gvfs-open` instead but I have no idea how to do that, if possible.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like I found the solution to my own question:

Dolphin obviously ignores the `[Default Applications]` in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but uses `[Added Associations]` in the same file. So the quick way how to change multiple file associations in Dolphin would be to copy all the lines under `[Default Applications]` (set with xdg-mime) and paste them to the same file with `[Added Associations]` before them instead. Most likely works the same with Konqueror and everything else using `kde-open`.

Comment: Works for Krusader