# Krusader: .txt file opened by Libreoffice5

Tags: nautilus, krusader

I am trying to open a '.txt' file in Krusader. I want it to be opened by the Ubuntu 17.10 editor 'Text', but when I press 'Return', the file is opened by LibreOffice 5 - very strange...

I have tried looking at Ubuntu Settings -> Details -> Default Applications, but there are only 6 'types', text not being one of them. 
When I hit 'Return' in the File Manager 'Files' (Nautilus) the file is opened correctly by 'Text'. So what is going on here? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to force Krusader to use Ubuntu's file associations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539494/how-to-force-krusader-to-use-ubuntus-file-associations/882214) contains 4 answers. I choose the "xdg-open %aCurrent%;" workaround. Very neat trick!